# Hyphenation in question titles

Tags: discussion

I know this is a site-wide feature, but this is becoming unbearable

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Examples 1 and 2 are execrable, borrowing [barbara beeton's understatement in a comment to a Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el/376201#comment1263928_376201).

Example 3 is very confusing

Example 4 shows that in most cases there is no space saving whatsoever.

I believe it would be possible to deactivate question title hyphenation on selected sites and that we should pressure the Powers to.

Comment: When I visit https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643984/why-are-showboxbreadth-and-showboxdepth-set-to-230-1-in-loggingall, the `hyphens` CSS property of the title is `manual`, and no hyphenation happens.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen The problem aren't the question pages, but the lists. There the `hyphens` CSS is set to `hyphens: auto !important;`